Percentile formula limited to lookup value in array in separate sheet
I have a dataset in Sheet 1 where the data forms a long vertical-scrolling list, i.e.
A            B            C        D
Location     Param        Value    Date
L1           Conductivity 1,250    01/02/2019
L2           Conductivity 850      01/02/2019
L1           Chloride     224      01/02/2019
L3           Conductivity 1,900    01/02/2019
L4           Chloride     450      01/02/2019
L4           Conductivity 1,100    01/02/2019
G1           Conductivity 1,250    01/02/2019
G2           Conductivity 1,150    01/02/2019
G3           Conductivity 1,050    01/02/2019
L1           Conductivity 1,299    30/02/2021
L2           Conductivity 857      30/02/2021

I then have, in a separate sheet, a 'lookup list' showing all unique locations with some other database information, i.e.
A            B            C
Location     Loc_group    Matrix
L1           Leachate     Water
L2           Leachate     Water
L3           Leachate     Water
L4           Leachate     Water
G1           Groundwater  Water
G2           Groundwater  Water
G3           Groundwater  Water

In a separate sheet again, I perform some statistics (the variable in Cell D1 of this third sheet is 'Conductivity' and the named range 'Date' refers to Sheet1!D:D).
I've been using the following formula to calculate percentiles based on other variables, such as limiting dates and parameter names, i.e.
=PERCENTILE.INC(IF((Sheet1!B:B=D$1)*(Date>43466)*(Date<45657),Sheet1!C:C),0.95)

The formula above gives the 95th percentile for all conductivity values in the date range 01 January 2019 to 31 December 2024, irrespective of their location group (loc_group).
What I need the formula to do, is the above, but also limiting it to only the values in the first sheet, which match the Loc_group criteria ('Leachate') in Column B of the second sheet.
Ideally this will be performed in the formula (but if it's really convoluted, I'm open to VBA).

Can you elaborate on what the result is you're getting? And/or what error you're receiving?

In essence, you want to return a list of anything within the specified date range that falls under the parameter 'Conductivity' in Column B, that comes from location L1, L2, L3, or L4 from Column A relative to Column B on Sheet2, that is above the 95th percentile of the included numbers? Or are you just trying to return what the 95th percentile of the included numbers is?

So add another condition: (LEFT(Sheet1!A:A)="L") or (XLOOKUP(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet2!A:A,Sheet2!B:B,"")="Leachate") ? (Better not reference whole columns. In Beta is trimrange references A:.A means column A from start to last used cell.)

@P.b Although in my example I've kept it simple, it's not really possible to trim characters as in the larger dataset there will be more complex location names of varying lengths. Hence the referral to the separate lookup list.

I had a hunch, hence the XLOOKUP alternative

@P.b. Thanks, works pefectly. I guess I haven't moved with the times - I wasn't aware of the XLOOKUP function which was added to Excel in 2019 - I've been a prolific user of index-match for my lookups for years...

Nothing wrong with the combo of index and match. But XLOOKUP and XMATCH make things easier. They can search backwards (last to first) for instance.

Here/screenshots refer:
=LET(x_,FILTER(Table1[Value],--ISNUMBER(MATCH(Table1[Location],FILTER(Table2[Location],--(Table2[Loc_group]=N4)),0))*(Table1[Date]<=M4)*(Table1[Date]>=L4)*(Table1[Param]=K4)),z_,PERCENTILE(x_,O4),z_)



Here:

Allows Dt_lower/Dt_upper (lower/upper dt bound resp) to be specified/vary [overwrite with static values as req)
Likewise for p-ile (can specify as 0.95 static as req/before)


Notes:

30/02/2019?  Assumed w/c 03/YY (28 or 29 days in Feb! ☺)
Assuming Office 365 compatible Excel: same as


JB-007
̿̿ ̿̿ ̿̿ ̿’̿’\̵͇̿̿\З= ( ▀ ͜͞ʖ▀) =Ε/̵͇̿̿/’̿’̿ ̿ ̿̿ ̿̿ ̿̿
